# How to target cell in 2nd row when there's a rowspan?

Tags: css, html-table

My CSS centers all the cells in a data table, except the cells in the first column are centered, like so:

```
td {text-align:center}
td:first-child {text-align:left}
```

That's all fine and good except for tables where any of the cells in the first column span multiple rows.  Of course a picture's worth a thousand words, so here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/michaelbluejay/qmGGG/1/

I know I can use inline CSS or classes on the offending cells to make them centered, but I'm hoping there's a general solution which doesn't require editing the <table> itself.  What do you think?

Comment: Classes seem like the most robust solution.

Comment: You could add a rowspan to all of the left-most cells, then use `td[rowspan]` to select them, but other than that, I can't think of anything. Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/jakelauer/qmGGG/2/

Comment: @Jake for that he is better off setting a class, something like `.first-row` or whatever... Seems more logical than using `rowspan` for all of them

Comment: As a matter of fact, why dont you just add a `.left-align` class to the rows you need to be left-aligned?

Comment: @GiovanniSilveira I'm aware of that. He specifically asked about how to avoid classes.

Comment: @Jake he said he was "hoping" to fix it other way. If its to add more html code, its cleaner and makes more sense to add a class, rather than a `rowspan=1` on all `<td>`s he wants to style.

Answer (score 0):

You can use colgroup for that.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_colgroup.asp

Don't forget to remove your td:first-child selector if you try.

```
<colgroup>
    <col />
    <col style="text-align:center;" />
    <col style="text-align:center;" />
</colgroup>
```

I used the inline styles just as an example. Put this in your css file of course.